What verb phrases can I replace with "do it" or "do that"? E.g.: "-I noticed a small crack in the wall. -I did it too / I did that too." — Is this OK?
from an answer on ell.stackexchange.com:

only certain kinds of actions can be "done"

I'm interested in what verb phrases can be replaced with "do + direct object" and what verb phrases cannot.
Is there any rule about it?
my own example:
A: I noticed a small crack in the wall.
(10) B: I did too.
Can I add a direct object after "did" here?
If I can, then what direct objects can I add?:
(11) I did it too.
(12) I did that too.
(13) I did this too.
(14) I did so too.
Which of (11-14) are correct and which are not and why?

Only 14, and it might seem excessively formal. Quite informal and very usual would be 'me too'.

@MichaelHarvey Does "I did so too" here mean "So did I too" or "So too did I"? Thanks.

"I did so too" means in AmE "I, too, noticed a crack" in that scenario. Surely the same in BrE?

Loviii, I don't know what you think is the difference between So did I too and So too did I.  To do so means to do something that has just been mentioned. Very usual and less informal than Michael's Me too would be So did I (it's unnecessary to include too).

@TimR Could you clarify please: when you say "I did so too" means "I, too, noticed a crack", then does this mean "do" in "do so" is an auxiliary or lexical verb?

@Lovii  If you're asking whether the average native speaker knows whether they're using the auxiliary or the lexical verb there, the answer to that is no.  My opinion is that "I did so too" is a case of allusion: 'I did [notice a crack] too", where "so" stands in for the original verb phrase, using the bare verb form.

I went there. -- I did too = "I did [go there] too"

As a learner (not a native speaker), you need to grasp the difference between an auxiliary do/does and a lexical use of the verb do. There's no other way to explain it. Fyi, I did so too is super formal and not used in an everyday context.

@Lambie "As a learner, you need to grasp the difference between an auxiliary "do/does" and a lexical use of the verb "do"" — But that's exactly what I asked: Is "do" in "do so" an auxiliary or lexical verb? What do you think the answer is here?

I didn't answer that specific form but I will, might, could do so. What do you think? :) Do so=do the thing the first verb states (first verb=answer, in this case). do so=means do that. So, it has to be lexical.

@Lambie "I didn't answer that specific form but I will, might, could do so" is an absolutely different example. Here, of course, "do" can't be an auxiliary because the auxiliary is "will/might/could". But is "did" in "I did so too" (where there aren't any modals after "I") an auxiliary or not?

@Loviii You are making me answer this again? Is that fair? The test is this: Do you notice the flowers in the garden in the evenings? Yes, I do. =auxiliary. Yes, I do so.=lexical. do so=do notice.

@Lambie "You are making me answer this again? Is that fair?" - I wrote you the previous comment here (not only under your answer) in order that if someone were to read only this section of comments (without reading that which is under your answer), they could see the full dialogue relating to the issue.

The OP's Question: my own example:
A: I noticed a small crack in the wall.
(10) B: I did too.
Verb: notice. Ergo, "I did too."| is right and short for:  "I noticed it too." It's the auxiliary used as a short answer.
The OP's Question:
Can I add a direct object after "did" here [with the verb notice]?
Answer: No, not for a verb like notice because noticing is not "doing something". It's a verb of perception here like see, notice, discover, find, hear, feel, and smell. As such, it takes an auxiliary in the short answer. But you can use: Yes, I noticed it.

Did you do your homework? Yes, I did. [auxiliary do]

Did you do your homework? Yes, I did it. is for a lexical use of the verb do.

Did you do your homework? No, not yet. But I will do so. do so replaces do homework. [lexical]



In OP's specific case it's "verb of perception", but I think the broader case is stative vs dynamic verbs. So just as I did it too doesn't work after He noticed [something], you can't idiomatically say I am it too as a rejoinder to He's cold.

@FumbleFingers Huh??

I mean I think your "verbs of perception" category is just a subset of "stative" verbs, which would also include A: "I'm hot!", where B's response "I'm it too!" is equally invalid, for the same reason (and it can't be contracted; it has to be "I am too!"). Although to be in that context is stative, it's not a verb of perception.

That's why I didn't say stative. It just adds to the complexity unnecessarily. :)

I don't think distinguishing stative & dynamic verbs is "unnecessary complexity" in this context - but if that's what you believe, I won't try to change your position.

"I will do so" is an absolutely different example. Here, of course, "do" can't be an auxiliary because the auxiliary is "will". But is "did" in "I did so too" (where there aren't any modals after "I") an auxiliary or not?

@Loviii No, it is not.  "|He spilled the dinner on the floor."  "I did so too". = did spill it on the floor. The auxiliary can be many things: I have done so too. I had done so too. etc. Same thing. The tense changes nothing at all. Read my comment under your question.

I can't understand one thing. You're saying it's not an auxiliary. But then in "He spilled the dinner on the floor. I did so too", you're saying "I did so too" = "I did spill it on the floor", where "did" in the right part of the equality is an auxiliary and hence "did" in the left part of the equality is an auxiliary too.

@Loviii I did so, I will do so, I have done so, I will have done so, I will be doing so, I had been doing so, I do so. replaces spill dinner on the floor. Yes, I did.=auxiliary. Yes, I did so=lexical.

Why? Because an auxiliary short answer can't take a direct object.
